# Dropdown list does not trigger javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I cannot get the following HTML to trigger my JS function:

**HTML:**

```
<table style="margin-bottom: 8px">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label><b>Select Language:</b></label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select class="dropdown" id="selectlanguage">
                <option id="enBtn">English</option>
                <option id="zhBtn">简体中文</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
 $("#enBtn").bind("click", function () {
    setLanguage("en");
      console.log("en");
  });

  $("#zhBtn").bind("click", function () {
    setLanguage("zh");
     console.log("zh");
  })
```

The `setlanguage` function works fine when I use the following HTML:

```
<div>  
    <a href="#" id="enBtn">English</a>  
    <a href="#" id="zhBtn">简体中文</a>  
</div>
```

But it does not work when I try to trigger with the dropdown list.

Comment: You have not bound anything to anchor ids `enBtn2` and `zhBtn2`, right? And also you have `setLanguage` method in somewhere. Can you share those?

Comment: enbtn2 is my mistake, now i fix it. setlanguage i will delete it just as  $("#zhBtn").bind("click", function () {
     console.log("zh");
  })    it will never reach console.log("zh")

Comment: `bind` is deprecated in the latest version of jquery, use `on` instead and when binding to a dropdown, use `change` instead of `click` (I don't think you can register click events on the options)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a select/dropdown you have to bind the handler to the select/dropdown and listen for change.

`$('#selectlanguage').change(setLanguage)`

```
<select class="dropdown" id="selectlanguage">
  <option id="enBtn" value="en">English</option>
  <option id="zhBtn" value="zh">简体中文</option>
</select>
```

and the handler:

```
function setLanguage() {
  console.log($(this).val());
}
```

if you don't want to touch your already written `setLanguage`-function:

`$('#selectlanguage').change(getLanguage)`

```
function getLanguage() {
  console.log($(this).val());
  setLanguage($(this).val());
  //or handle what is in $(this).val() however you want to
}
```

Comment: so, how do i  setLanguage("en") according to click #enBtn,? .change(setLanguage) does not specific enBtn orZhBtn

Comment: I updated my answer. Be aware of the `value`-property in each `<option>`

Comment: setlanguage itself has parameter .i do not tend to rewrite setlanguage function..do you have a way do not touch setlanguage function and solve the problem.. for example, i click English in dropdown list and then language setup to english   $("#enBtn").bind("click", function () {
    setLanguage("en");
   console.log("en");
  });

Comment: I updated again, so just put another function as handler in between your `selects` and `setLanguage`